# Pausa al saltar de un frame a otro en un video

Tags: unity3d, video, unity

Cuando hago un salto de un frame a otro, el video se pausa durante medio segundo. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que eso no suceda?

El siguiente código es de Unity3D engine:

```
if (videoPlayer[0].frame >= 400)

    videoPlayer[0].frame= Otro_frame;

}
```

Cuando hace el cambio de un frame a otro, hace una pausa. Lo que quisiera saber es si es posible hacer un cambio de un frame a otro de una manera más limpia (sin esa pausa de 0.5 seg).